# Picking a JavaScript button in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, css, htmlunit

In AliX, this page for example https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956185908.html
how do you pick the particular country and colour?

For example, following js configure as country:

```
"skuPropertyValues":[
{"propertyValueDisplayName":"China","propertyValueId":201336100,"propertyValueIdLong":201336100,"propertyValueName":"China","skuPropertySendGoodsCountryCode":"CN","skuPropertyTips":"China","skuPropertyValueShowOrder":2,"skuPropertyValueTips":"China"},
{"propertyValueDisplayName":"GERMANY","propertyValueId":201336101,"propertyValueIdLong":201336101,"propertyValueName":"GERMANY","skuPropertySendGoodsCountryCode":"DE","skuPropertyTips":"GERMANY","skuPropertyValueShowOrder":2,"skuPropertyValueTips":"GERMANY"},
{"propertyValueDisplayName":"SPAIN","propertyValueId":201336104,"propertyValueIdLong":201336104,"propertyValueName":"SPAIN","skuPropertySendGoodsCountryCode":"ES","skuPropertyTips":"SPAIN","skuPropertyValueShowOrder":2,"skuPropertyValueTips":"SPAIN"},
{"propertyValueDisplayName":"Russian Federation","propertyValueId":201336103,"propertyValueIdLong":201336103,"propertyValueName":"Russian Federation","skuPropertySendGoodsCountryCode":"RU","skuPropertyTips":"Russian Federation","skuPropertyValueShowOrder":2,"skuPropertyValueTips":"Russian Federation"}]},
```

I'm not sure how to pick one through JavaScript or am I looing at the wrong thing, would it CS and picking up a div tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable js support and wait after retrieving the page until all the javascript is done. The js code will generate div's from you code above (use page.asXML() to get an idea of the page fro the viewpoint of HtmlUnit.

If the div's are there you can click() on them - like on any other html element. This click should trigger the same js code like in real browsers.

To find the div elements please have a look at https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html; there are many different options listed.

Comment: I have tested by enabling the and I have noticed the list of Div tags created . just not sure how to iterate the div's and click on them.

Answer (score 0):

Like @RBRi said, use the click method on the element. To choose the element (DIV in this case) you can use the getbyxpath method:

Starting from the page you can access using the XPATH of the element. The XPATH can be easily obtained using the browser inspect tool and copying the full XPATH of the div (right click over the div and use the copy option). For the purpose of your URL, "CHINA" element has the XPATH: */html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/* "GERMANY": */html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div/span*

```
page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956185908.html");
// get china div using xpath
element = ((HtmlElement)page1.getByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/").get(0));
// Click over china
element.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
```

If you want to iterate over the list of countries you can use the same approach, but this time copy the XPATH of the div that contains all the countries, get that element, and from this element then iterate by getting the divs. In this case, you can use the attribute "class" to get those elements:

```
page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32956185908.html");
element = ((HtmlElement)page1.getByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/div[1]/ul").get(0); // Get the div that contains all countries
List<HtmlElement> elements = element.getElementsByAttribute("div", "class", "sku-property-text");
```

Then you can iterate over the list of elements and click the one you prefer.

```
:
  choosenElement.click();
:
```